# Deploying code without SVN Bindings

Tags: svn, netbeans

All,

We have a PHP project in SVN. We develop code and do SVN checkins and checkouts using Netbeans 6.7 PHP IDE.

Each week, we need to deploy a new release to a test environment. We do not want to deploy it with SVN Bindings in it. How can we do that? Do we need to create Bindings or tags? If so, how to create them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html), which "...exports a clean directory tree from the working copy" is what you're after. Beware, however, that it just exports data without performing necessary renames and deletions, so if you will be exporting over the same destination you can eventually end up with lots of junk.